# Content script's document.getElementById() returns null?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Working on a an add-on with multiple pages in which I call the content script and the corresponding HTML page from the add-on script.When I try to fetch a value of text box in the HTML page why do I get null.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Dummy Page 
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="login-field" placeholder="username" id="usermail" value="heelo">
        <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
        <input type="password" class="login-field" placeholder="password" id="password" value="heells">
        <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
    </body>
</html>
```

ContentJS

```
self.port.on("get-first-para", getFirstPara);

function getFirstPara() {
    var userId = document.getElementById("usermail").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (userId.length > 0 && pass.length > 0) {
        var firstPara = userId + " ** " + pass;
        self.port.emit("first-para", firstPara);
    }
}
```

Addon Js

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageWorkers = require("sdk/page-worker");
var self = require("sdk/self");
require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
    id: "Mailer",
    label: "Click to start",
    icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: handleClick
});
var textChk = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    position: {
        top: 0,
        right: 0
    },
    hight: 100,
    contentURL: data.url("textChk.html"),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("content.js")
});
function handleClick() {
    textChk.show();
    pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url("content.js")
    });
    pageWorker.port.on("first-para", function(firstPara) {
      console.log(firstPara);
    });
    pageWorker.port.emit("get-first-para");
}
```

Need to know know how can i get off the null error ?

Comment: you're sending `get-first-para` to the page-worker, which has no content, not the Panel with the html content

Comment: I am passing 'firstPara' that contains the values of usermail and password received from the html page to get-first-para to emit it to the addon js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are emitting "get-first-para" to `pageWorker` - in your code pageWorker has **no content**, but has the **SAME** script as the **panel** (textChk) ... textChk on the other hand **has** (html) content **and** the same content.js - did you perhaps mean to do the following?

```
function handleClick() {
    textChk.show();
    textChk.port.on("first-para", function(firstPara) {
      console.log(firstPara);
    });
    textChk.port.emit("get-first-para");
}
```

Comment: Buddy page-workers are  for the inter js communication where as the panel is showing the the html content that needs to appear on request by the code. refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Communicating_with_the_add-on and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel  Thus the answer is not useful however thanks for trying :)

Comment: Buddy, your page worker has no effing content ... did you notice how the panel documentation **does not mention the need for page-worker**, buddy?

Comment: Go through the first link you would get my point... I would be happy to be wrong if this solves the problem :)

Comment: I use your code, I get an error `JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` ... I use my code, I get `console.log: buddy: heelo ** heells` on the console - there's still an issue, but it isn't a null getElementById result

Comment: It would be great if you could more explanatory so that js newbies like me could understand it  as it Seems to work for me too but am still unable to understand the reason... however am really happy to be wrong thanks for help...please refer to my other questions too..Thanks a lot

Comment: I thought I explained it ... you're emitting to a page worker that has no content ... no content, so no possibility that getElementById could possibly ever work